# What does the phrase 豪华名贵 mean in Dave Wong's song "爱不起"?

Tags: translation, idioms, chengyu

**Cross-post notice**

Here is another Quora cross-post, this one 21 days old and marked as needing to be in English. [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/In-the-Chinese-song-in-the-source-titled-%E7%88%B1%E4%B8%8D%E8%B5%B7-what-is-the-meaning-of-%E8%B1%AA%E5%8D%8E%E5%90%8D%E8%B4%B5-in-the-final-phrase-%E2%80%9CThe-more-youre-fascinated-with-me-haohua-minggui-the-more-I-find-I-can%E2%80%99t-love-you%E2%80%9D).

**Question**

At the end of [爱不起](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Enz5egwcAA&feature=youtu.be), there is the sentence "越是迷住我 豪华名贵 越是发现爱不起". The first and third segments are "The more you are fascinated with me" and "the more I discover I cannot love you", unless I'm much mistaken. The middle segment is a set phrase I cannot figure out the meaning of in this sentence. So I ask:

> In the Chinese song in the source, titled 爱不起, what is the meaning of 豪华名贵 in the final phrase “The more you're fascinated with me, [haohua minggui], the more I find I can’t love you”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"豪華名貴" roughly is luxury & precious goods & lifestyles

the theme of the song is a poor male like / love a rich female. so, there's the lyric "而能力上永遠付不起" (can't never pay); which accord with the song title.

"愛不起" is caused by "付不起" :(

Comment: So 而能力上永遠付不起 would be "and I can never pay you back with [my] abilities" (or maybe 能力 -> richness)? And 豪华名贵 would be "rich and full of luxury (as you are)" referring to the girl, right?

Comment: 能力 --> (my) economic ability